# Reference current file name

Tags: debugging, go

Is there a way to get a current source file name in Go? And for instrance `fmt.Println` it. (Like you could do in `C` with `__FILE__` macro.)

That's for debugging purpose, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

[`runtime.Caller(0)`](https://godoc.org/runtime#Caller) should return a few items, one of them being the file name of the function it was called from.

The parameter indicates the depth of functions to skip in case you want to abstract this functionality to a separate function but want to get the file name of where it's called from.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging, use the log package and enable the log.Lshortfile or log.Llongfile flag:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    shortLogger := log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile)
    shortLogger.Println("short")

    longLogger := log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.LstdFlags|log.Llongfile)
    longLogger.Println("long")
}

// 2009/11/10 23:00:00 main.go:10: short
// 2009/11/10 23:00:00 /tmp/sandbox813987715/main.go:13: long
```

https://play.golang.org/p/2X7IeJHSmk